# Displaying the images up and down in css

Tags: html, css

I want to display three images in a single so i have written css for that to display images in a single row and center of the block but the problem is one of the image is going slight up.If i write css for that to display at same height it is moving all the three divs.Here is the code for that.

```css
 .member1 {
 width:250px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:30px;
    }
    .member1 + .member1{ 
     width:250px;
     height:200px;
     display:inline-block;
     margin-right:30px;
     }
     .member2{
  width:250px;
     height:200px;
     display:inline-block;
     margin-right:30px;
      }
     .member-details {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     }
```

```html
<div class="member-details">                 
               <div class="member2 clearfix ">
                 <figure> <img src="http://server.com/bar/image01.png" class="member-image"   width="222" height="222"> </figure>

                 <div class="overlay4">
                   <div class="overlay3">
                     <h5><a href="http://server.com/bar/fgh/">Sr. Advocate </a></h5>
                     <p><a href="http://server.com/bar/fgh/">fgh</a></p>                     
                   </div>
                </div>
               </div>               
               <div class="member1 ">
                 <figure> <img src="http://server.com/bar/image03.png" class="member-image" alt=""  width="222" height="222"> </figure>
                 <div class="overlay4">
                   <div class="overlay3">
                     <h5><a href="http://server.com/bar/abc/">Advocate </a></h5>
                     <p><a href="http://server.com/bar/abc/">abc</a></p>                     
                   </div>
                </div>
               </div>               
               <div class="member1 ">
                 <figure> <img src="http://server.com/bar/image02.png" class="member-image" alt="" width="222" height="222"> </figure>
                 <div class="overlay4">
                   <div class="overlay3">
                     <h5><a href="http://server.com/bar/xyz/">Advocate  Member</a></h5>
                     <p><a href="http://server.com/bar/xyz/">XYZ</a></p>                     
                   </div>
                </div>
               </div>     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Use bootstrap, and you will able to do design, without any problem,

So i write following code, which may help you have a look.
and this is link of jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/7b5dzp9o/9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/photos_96dp.png"></div>
    <div class="col-4"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/photos_96dp.png"></div>
    <div class="col-4"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/photos_96dp.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't see the images (links are broken) and so the problem. But if you are only trying to display images in a row and centered together, i suggest you to check [CSS Flexbox].(https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)